# the provided package is already installed and reinstallation of the package was blocked

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1-universal

I'm developing Windows 8.1 Universal application with Visual Studio 2015. After creating app packages successfully, I'm unable to deploy app into Windows Phone device. Facing issue like "the provided package is already installed and reinstallation of the package was blocked". Please help me. Please find attached screenshot for reference purpose. 
[image: Error link]

Comment: Sounds like you need to uninstall the old version before the new one will install

Comment: did same thing and restarted also...

Comment: Are you developing a Windows 8.1 Universal application? If so please use [tag:windows-8.1-universal] instead as [tag:win-universal-app] is more used for UWP questions.

Comment: And for your error, according to [MSDN document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973484(v=vs.85).aspx), you may get this error if installing a package that has the same identity as a package that is already installed, but the package contents are different. If you are updating a package, you must increment the package version.

Comment: If your new package is resigned, it can not be identified by your previously installed package. I think you could delete the old package before installing the new one or increment the version number of the package and rebuild and resign the package.

Answer (score 0):

You’re probably not signed in. I was struggling with this, and when I signed into my account everything worked